# Count number of times a sub record used a main record in access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a main list of part #s and I am trying to run a query that says how many times the part # was quoted and how many times it was ordered but seems I am doing something wrong. The Quote and Order ID numbers are unique yet there are 6500 rows total but the query seems to return 38000 for some parts.

```
sqlselectstring = "Select  dp.PartNumber, count (fqp.fk_spQuoteID) as [# Times    Quoted],count( fop.fk_spOrderId) as [# Times Ordered] " & _
"From ((DimProduct As dp LEFT JOIN FactOrderProduct AS fop ON dp.PartNumber=fop.PartNumber) LEFT JOIN FactQuoteProduct as fqp on dp.PartNumber=fqp.PartNumber) " & _
"Group By dp.PartNumber;"
```

Comment: Use inline views to get the counts before the joins.  The cardinality between all 3 tables is artificially inflating the counts of the two being left joined.

Comment: You should use inner join on behalf of left join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the 1-M between DimProduct and the other two tables, you either need to get the counts before you join using inline views:

```
SELECT dp.PartNumber
      , FQPcnt as [# Times    Quoted]
      , FOPCnt as [# Times Ordered] 
FROM DimProduct As dp 
LEFT JOIN (Select PartNumber, count(fk_spOrderID) as FOPCnt FROM FactOrderProduct GROUP BY PartNumber) AS fop 
  ON dp.PartNumber=fop.PartNumber 
LEFT JOIN (Select PartNumber, count(fk_spQuoteID) as FQPCnt FROM FactQuoteProduct GROUP BY PartNumber)
  fqp on dp.PartNumber=fqp.PartNumber
Group By dp.PartNumber;
```

Or you have to generate the counts separately and union the results; but that gives multiple record...

Or (I can't remember if access supports it....) Use correlated sub queries...

```
SELECT dp.PartNumber
      , (Select count(fk_spQuoteID) as FQPCnt FROM FactQuoteProduct FQP WHERE dp.PartNumber=fqp.PartNumber) as [# Times    Quoted]
      , (Select count(fk_spOrderID) as FOPCnt FROM FactOrderProduct FOP WHERE DP.PartNumber=FOP.PartNumber) as [# Times Ordered] 
FROM DimProduct As dp
```

Comment: It also helps if I I don't have 4 copy and paste errors.  corrected names of fk_spQuoteID as well as table FactQuoteProduct

Comment: Access supports the correlated subquery - that was the answer I was going to give, but didn't have time to test it.

Comment: Thanks I ended up coming up with the running the counts separately and union on my own but good to know there is a correlated query I can use in future

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sqlselectstring = "Select  dp.PartNumber, count (fqp.fk_spQuoteID) as [# Times    Quoted],count( fop.fk_spOrderId) as [# Times Ordered] " & _
"From ((DimProduct As dp INNER JOIN FactOrderProduct AS fop ON dp.PartNumber=fop.PartNumber) INNER JOIN FactQuoteProduct as fqp on dp.PartNumber=fqp.PartNumber) " & _
"Group By dp.PartNumber;"
```

Comment: gives me the same result